# Castalia 3.2 sleep in application

Tags: sleep, intervals, omnet++

I’m developing an  application in Castalia 3.2. 
How can I change to sleep mode during a time in the application code so that received messages are discarded and then change to listen mode or transmit mode?
Note that I do not want to use backoff neither TunableMAC nor other Mac protocols.

Answer (score 0):

To control the Radio module from the Application module, you can use the control commands which are described in section 4.2.4 of the user manual titled "Dynamically adjusting radio parameters".

If the application module controls the Radio then it's important to be the single point of control, which means the MAC (which normally controls the state of the radio) should not interfere. For this reason you should use the BypassMAC module (which essentially means "no MAC").

Finally, I would advise you to use the latest version of Castalia found at Github. There are several bug fixes and new features compared to version 3.2.